# Thrown IllegalArgumentException when using java.nio

Tags: java, android, nio

Trying to download file by url. For that using java.nio library. The code above work perfect for sdk 24 and above but getting IllegalArgumentException for android sdk 23 and below. I'm getting the error when trying transfer the data. Dear Friends can you please clarify which is the problem.

```
    private void downloadFile(final String itemUrl) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = null;
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = null;

                String root = 
                getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
                File myDir = new File(root + "/downloadedSongs");
                if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdirs();
                }

                File file = new File(myDir, itemTitle);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(itemUrl);
                    readableByteChannel = 
                    Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
                    fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
      fOutStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    orderAction = Enums.OrderAction.Delete;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    orderAction = Enums.OrderAction.Delete;
                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (fOutStream != null) {
                            fOutStream.close();
                        }
                        if (readableByteChannel != null) {
                           readableByteChannel.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioExObj) {
                        orderAction = Enums.OrderAction.Delete;
                    }
                    closeNotification(orderAction);
                }
            }
    }).start();
}
```

[image]

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: position=0 count=9223372036854775807 at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(FileChannelImpl.java:370) at am.itsoft.youtomp3.services.DnlService$1.run(DnlService.java:169) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Please post the error with stack trace.

Comment: Dear Friend, I have updated the post

Comment: Ummm.   A screenshot with the string 'stackTrace' in it is not really a stack trace...

Comment: This is all which I found in firbase crashlitics:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: position=0 count=9223372036854775807
       at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(FileChannelImpl.java:370)
       at am.itsoft.youtomp3.services.DnlService$1.run(DnlService.java:169)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Can you expand the stacktrace item in the second screenshot and post what you see there?

Comment: Dear Friend, I have updated the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in this argument: Long.MAX_VALUE

Right code:

```
FileChannel destChannel = fOutStream.getChannel();
long blockSize;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
  long blockSize = Long.MAX_VALUE;
} else {
  long blockSize = 8*1024;
}
long position = 0;
long loaded;
while ((loaded = destChannel.transferFrom(readableByteChannel, position, blockSize)) > 0) {
   position += loaded;
}
```